# Mapping dictionary of lists to a pandas df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I have a dictionary which contains a id and a list of corresponding values for that id.
I am attempting to map this dictionary to a pandas df.
The df contains the same id to map to, but it needs to map the items in that list in order of appearance within the df.

For example:

```
sample_dict = {0:[0.1,0.4,0.5], 1:[0.2,0.14,0.3], 2:[0.2,0.1,0.4]}
```

The df looks like:
[image]
The output of mapping the dictionary to the df would look like:
[image]
Sorry for typing the table out like this, the actual df is very large, and I'm still new to stack exchange and pandas.

The end output should just map the id list value in order to the players as they appear in order as the df is sorted by id and then player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `explode` with `reindex`

```
df['new'] = pd.Series(sample_dict).reindex(df.id.unique()).explode().values
df
Out[140]: 
   id  Player   new
0   0       1   0.1
1   0       2   0.4
2   0       3   0.5
3   1       1   0.2
4   1       2  0.14
5   1       3   0.3
6   2       1   0.2
7   2       2   0.1
8   2       3   0.4
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @Redratz please try to update your pandas ~new function added after 0.25